# free homotopy groups -- when do they exist?

Tags: homotopy-theory, at.algebraic-topology

Let (X,x) be a pointed space.  There is an action of π<sub>1</sub>(X,x) on π<sub>n</sub>(X,x) -- determined by considering π<sub>n</sub>(X,x)=π<sub>n-1</sub>(Ω<sub>x</sub>X,**x**), where Ω<sub>x</sub>X denotes the space of loops in X based at x, and **x** denotes the constant loop -- given simply by conjugation.  We can speak unambiguously of π<sub>n</sub>(X), the *free* (i.e., not necessarily basepoint-preserving) homotopy group exactly when this action is trivial.

On an algebraic level I'm fine with this, but I'm having trouble envisioning how a homotopy class might be conjugated to a different homotopy class in this way.  Besides my admittedly small collection of toy examples, my issue could also be that I'm mainly thinking about π<sub>1</sub>, in which case it might (???) be that the action *is* trivial.  (I seem to recall that before learning about general homotopy theory, I heard a statement along the lines of "for path-connected spaces, you may as well ignore basepoints".  Certainly the groups are all isomorphic, but I'm not certain whether there is a unique natural isomorphism.)

Also, are there (necessary and/or sufficient) conditions for when the π<sub>1</sub> action on π<sub>n</sub> will or won't be trivial, and does this depend on n?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For the last part of your question: given a group π<sub>1</sub> which acts on an abelian group π<sub>n</sub>, there is always as space X with these homotopy groups with this action, and you can manufacture one using Eilenberg-MacLane spaces.  You can make the group π<sub>1</sub> act on the Eilenberg-MacLane space K(π<sub>n</sub>,n) in such a way that realizes the action on π<sub>n</sub>, and then use this to build a space as a fibration X-->K(π<sub>1</sub>,1) with fiber K(π<sub>n</sub>,n).  So the only general limitation is in how the group π<sub>1</sub> can act on the group π<sub>n</sub>.

There is one condition on a space X which implies the action is trivial: if X is a loop space (i.e., X is homotopy equivalent to ΩY for some Y), then the action of π<sub>1</sub>(X) on π<sub>n</sub>(X) is always trivial; the idea is that ΩX=Ω<sup>2</sup>Y, in which loop composition is commutative up to homotopy.

Comment: More generally, the action of \pi_1 on \pi_n will be trivial if X is an H-space.

Comment: Assuming that the H-space is connected.

Answer (score 5):

If you are thinking about π<sub>1</sub>, the action is just that by conjugation in this group, so is trivial iff the fundamental group is abelian.

I think the easist place to see the nontriviality of this action in higher dimensions is for the space S<sup>1</sup> v S<sup>n</sup>. By considering its universal cover and using Hurewicz's theorem, one can see that π<sub>n</sub> = Z[t, t<sup>-1</sup>] (= Z<sup>infty</sup>), the ring of Laurent polynomials in a single variable t (as an additive group). You must then exercise the imagination to convince yourself that 1 in Z = π<sub>1</sub> acts as multiplication by t.

Comment: You don't need imagination to see that π_1 acts by t -- this is exactly what you are proving when you compute π_n = Z[t,t^-1]. Just go to the definition of the action of π_1 on π_n.

Answer (score 3):

Just to make explicit what was implicit in the above answers -- while pi_1(X,v) is isomorphic to pi_1(X,w) for all v and w, the isomorphism depends on a choice of path from v to w.  This isomorphism will be natural in the sense that it is independent of this choice of path if and only if pi_1(X) is abelian.

Comment: Right, and the isomorphism only depends on the homotopy class of the chosen path.  In other words, we can always interpret pi_n(X) as a local system of groups on X.  The OP's question then is about when this local system is trivial.